# How can I clear a search input when user change a page?

Tags: blazor

How can I clear a search input when user change a page?

I have a search component, it has an input and it redirects to /posts/{SearchTerm}:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div>
    <input type="text" @bind="SearchTerm" />
    <a @onclick="Search"></a>
</div>

@code {
    public string SearchTerm = "";

    private void Search()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"posts/{SearchTerm}");
    }
}
```

It is placed on MainLayout.razor:

```
<SearchForm />
```

And this is my Posts.razor page:

```
@page "/posts"
@page "/posts/{SearchTerm}"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div>@SearchTerm</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string SearchTerm { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;
    }

    private void HandleLocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchTerm = ""; // this doesn't clear the search input
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= HandleLocationChanged;
    }
}
```

How can I clear the search input from Pages.razor?

Comment: I think you should clear it after you Navigate:

`private void Search()
{
     NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"posts/{SearchTerm}");
     SearchTerm = "";
}`

Comment: Hmm - OK but then a user have to write something once again if he isn't satisfied search results. He can't modify a search term because it was cleared. I would like to clear it only when he leaves the Posts.razor page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the navigation check in the wrong place.

Here's your Posts page:

```
@page "/posts"
@page "/posts/{SearchTerm}"
<h3>Search</h3>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    @this.SearchTerm
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
}
```

Here's your Search Component:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
// Note you must implement IDisposable to use Dispose
@implements IDisposable

<div>
    <input type="text" @bind="SearchTerm" />
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" @onclick="Search">Search</button>
</div>

@code {
    public string SearchTerm = "";

    private void Search()
        =>  NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"posts/{SearchTerm}");

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        =>  NavigationManager.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;

    private void HandleLocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Needs to identify when the page is not the search page - may need some tweeking
        if (!e.Location.Contains("/posts"))
        {
            SearchTerm = ""; 
            // Need to call StateHasChanged as this is normal event driven rather than UI Event driven
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
        =>  NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= HandleLocationChanged;
}
```

And the MainLayout:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>StackOverflow.GenericComponent</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <SearchComponent />
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: woooow it works!!!!!!! thank you so much @MrC aka Shaun Curtis  :)